# Loopback 3 discards error information on multiple validation errors, turning 422 to 500, how can I solve that?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I'm migrating from Loopback 2 tot 3.

I currently have an issue with validation errors and strong-error-handler

When I post a bulk create which results in multiple validation errors, those get returned as an array of ValidationErrors.
Those errors get grouped by strong-error handler in a 500 internal server error, which is how it was before, but the details of the errors get discarded, when debug is set to false.

In my example I upload an array of tags, but for each tag, a uniqueness validation is executed. When 2 or more tags are already in the database, I have an array of errors, instead of a single validation error

I need a way to determine why the validation failed on the client side, but the details of the errors are discarded now.

Am I doing something wrong here, or should this be considered as a bug?

Answer (score 1):

From the [strongloop error handler](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-strong-error-handler.html) documentation in loopback,

> In production mode, strong-error-handler omits details from error responses to prevent leaking sensitive information:

More information

- For 5xx errors, the output contains only the status code and the status name from the HTTP specification.
- For 4xx errors, the output contains the full error message (error.message) and the contents of the details property (error.details) that ValidationError typically uses to provide machine-readable details about validation problems. It also includes error.code to allow a machine-readable error code to be passed through which could be used, for example, for translation.

> Am I doing something wrong here, or should this be considered as a bug?

No this is the intended behaviour

#### Safe error fields

You can set the [stack trace as "safe-error-field"](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-strong-error-handler.html#safe-error-fields) so that it will be displayed in production.
For example, the `stack` field is not displayed by default if you run the loopback in production mode.
If you still want to display the stack field, then change the config json in the `server/middleware.json`

```
"final:after": {
    "strong-error-handler": {
      "params": {
        "safeFields": ["stack"]
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thx for your answer Santosh. I didn't know about the safe-error-field. But I think that approach will expose the fields on all errors, and I only want the validation errors.

Comment: @Ernie In loopback 2, the error details were sent for all kinds of error, or only when validation error occurred?

Comment: The docs say, details are typically for validation errors, but I'm not sure if they are used elsewhere. It's not stated explicitly